# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client when trying to authenticate Next.js app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Trying to connect `nextjs` application to `Rails API`, after signing in getting this error:

> ```
> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
> at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:558:11)
> ```

I think the problem is in my router, so code is here:

```
import Router from 'next/router';

export const redirect = (url, ctx) => {
  if (typeof ctx === 'undefined') {
    Router.push(url);
  } else {
    const res = ctx.res;
    if (res) {
      res.writeHead(302, { Location: url });
      res.end();
    } else {
      Router.push(url);
    }
  }
}
```

`Rails` returns `200` status to me